# Is Event Sourcing applicable for batch inputs?

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-computing, microservices, event-sourcing

I have a use case where the inputs to the application comes in batches of XML files. For example, a nightly batch of bank transactions. I am trying to see if I can use event sourcing to create a log of events. Based on what I read so far, the examples seems to be based on user driven input (click streams, updates from a user interface etc.,). Is event sourcing using a distributed log mechanism(like Kafka) a valid approach for batch/file based inputs?

Below is the approach I would like to take:

1. Accept input as a batch in file/xml
2. Run some basic validations in the memory.
3. Convert the batch input into a series of events
4. Write the event log to a Kafka topic(s).
5. Use the event log to store the data into the database, send the events 
   to a search engine, update caches, run spark jobs to do aggregations 
   etc.,
6. Repeat the process for other incoming batches.

If this approach is not efficient, what other options are available for distributed processing of such inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Are your inputs coming from something that looks like an event storage? I.e. a database that acts as an immutable source of truth, of append only events.

**If that is the case, you have the foundation to use event sourcing, and additionally CQRS**. (They're not the same thing)

What you would have to realize is that the so called write side / command side... has already been done for you.

The incoming batch of XML files with transactions... each transaction is an event already. It doesn't sound like you need to convert these to events, to then put these into Kafka. You can just map these to something you can put into Kafka, and then all subscribers of the topics can do stuff accordingly.

**Effectively you would be implementing the read side of Event Sourcing + CQRS**.

**In practical terms**, unless you are going to be doing things on the write side (where the xml files are generated / where user input is received)... **I wouldn't worry too much about the subtleties** of event sourcing as it relates to DDD and CQRS. I would **simply think of what you're doing as a way to distribute your data to multiple services**.

And make sure to consider how caches, search engines, etc. will only be updated whenever you get those XML files.

Answer (score 1):

If each individual event in these xml files has a timestamp then you can think of the output to Kafka as just a steam of late arriving events. Kafka allows you to set the event time on these messages to be the timestamp of the event rather than the time it was ingested to Kafka. In that way, any downstream processing apps like Kafka Streams can put the event into the right temporal context and aggregate into the proper time windows or session windows or even join with other realtime inputs